# Starting a new database driven python web application would you use a javascript widget framework? If so which framework?

Tags: javascript, python, frameworks

I am starting a new web application project. I want to use python as I am using it at my bread-and-butter-job.

However I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Some things I have thought about:

- AJAX would be nice if it’s not too much of a hazzle.
- It is best if the licensing allows commercialization but is not crucial at this point.
- It could also be funny to try out the Google App Engine if the tools will let me.

Should I be using a javascript UI framework or should I go for standard HTML forms?

Which framework would you recommend?

Answer (score 4):

[jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/)? Though its [UI](http://ui.jquery.com/) components are perhaps not up to the very best (but lots of work appears to be done in that area), jQuery itself seems to be on track to become the de facto JS standard library. It is both MIT or GPL licensed so commercial use is ok (and costless).

Answer (score 1):

I heartily suggest [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) + [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/).  I think they cover most of the bases you are looking at and they are very straight-forward to get started with.  Also you could use them on the GAE if that is the route you decide to take, although you should keep in mind that the GAE does not support Cron jobs, which can limit your functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I'd take a look at [web2py](http://web2py.com/). It's a full-stack framework that requires no configuration and is easy to try out - everything can be driven via a web interface if you choose. I've dabbled with other frameworks and it's by far the easiest to setup and includes lots of helpful things for free. The documentation is good and there is a howto for getting it to work under Google App Engine. It comes with libraries and a howto for Ajax. As far as I remember the licence doesn't restrict using it in commercial applications.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ExtJS](http://extjs.com/).  It's got the best widget library out there.  They offer a commercial license and an open-source license.  There are several python developers in the community and there is some integration with Google APIs.

Answer (score 1):

web2py uses jQuery